# Econometrics: Creating Impulse Response Functions

Tags: econometrics, impulse-response, eviews

I am currently busy studying asymmetric price transmission in the global stainless steel value chain.

I have not been able to replicate the impulse response functions that are shown below.

I am more than happy to provide additional information and supporting documentation.

Any and all assistance/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If anyone is able to assist is would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I guess that when you would provide data and shown what you've tried (i.e. the code), it would be easier to get a helpful answer.